# VBA Do Until Loop Issue

Tags: excel, vba

I want to write a simple code to do a loop until (or while) a condition is met or while it is unmet but I am meeting an endless loop code :

```
Sub MyMacro()

    NamedRangedForMacro = Range("MyNamedRangeInMyExcel")

    Do Until NamedRangedForMacro = 0
        
            Range("MyNamedRangeInMyExcel_copy").Copy
            Range("MyNamedRangeInMyExcel_paste").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            
    Loop

End Sub
```

I am struggling to understand why I get into an endless loop as the value clearly reaches 0 after a few copy/paste.

I tried Until/While, insert some End statements but without success

Comment: You never change the value of the variable `NamedRangedForMacro`, so either it is `True` and you are caught in an endless loop of it is `False` and the loop is not entered at all

Comment: Thank you, this was an unnecessary line that I removed it and it works.